# remove top 6 lines from json response

Tags: python, json, spyder

I am performing a GET request from jira and the first 6 rows shows like this in the response:

```
{
    "expand": "schema,names",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 50,
    "total": 1253,
    "issues": [
```

The problem i have with this is when i send the whole response to my external program it sees it all as one json string rather than split each event. The python script i use is as per the below:

```
import requests
import json

class BearerAuth2(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
    def __call__(self, s):
        s.headers["authorization"] = "tok" + self.token
        return s

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}

res = requests.get('https://ourdomain/rest/api/2/search?jql="Delivery Team" is not EMPTY&fields=comment, summary, customfield_10004, customfield_12802, body, assignee, Key&maxResults=50', headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))

res2 = requests.get('https://ourdomain/rest/api/2/search?jql="Delivery Team" is not EMPTY&fields=comment, summary, customfield_10004, customfield_12802, body, assignee, Key&maxResults=1000&startAt=1001', headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))

payload2=res.json()
payload3=res2.json()

tok1 = requests.post('https://http-inputs-externalprogram', data=json.dumps(payload2), headers=headers, auth=BearerAuth2('token'))
```

is there anything i can add here to remove those rows as when i done it manually and sent it to my external program all the events were split?

Comment: It might not matter, but is there a reason you don't use `json=payload2` as opposed to `data=json.dumps(payload2)`?  You should be able to omit the content-type header in this case as well.  Also, what do you mean by "split each event?"  The external problem is parsing the json into some object, right?

Comment: Hi Nathan, json=payload2 doesnt work and says "module 'json' has no attribute 'payload2'" as im using a POST from requests and doesnt seem to like it so thats why i use json.dumps. when i mean split what is happening is when i send the event that has come through from the first GET to the POST external program it cannot parse the data correctly and sees it as one large event rather than being multiple events in the json payload (which is 1000 events). Any ideas how i could omit in the content type header?